# AD RMS Managed Code Error The system cannot find the file specified. HRESULT: 0x80070002

Tags: active-directory, rights-management

I'm new to Active Directory Rights Management Services (AD RMS) and I'm developing an application to use AD RMS to encrypt some documents. I'm using the interop example and I get the error - The system cannot find the file specified. HRESULT: 0x80070002 - when I try to run the code below:

I get the error when I try to run this statement:

Collection ipcTemplates = IPC.GetTemplates();

```
internal static class IPC
{
     static IPC()
     {
          SafeNativeMethods.IpcInitialize();
     }

     public static Collection<TemplateInfo> GetTemplates()
     {
          Collection<TemplateInfo> templates = null;

          try
          {
               templates = SafeNativeMethods.IpcGetTemplateList(null, true, true,
                                false, false, null, null);
          }
          catch (Exception /*ex*/)
          {
              /* TODO: Add logging */
              throw; 
          }

          return templates;
     }
}
```

Stack Trace:

The system cannot find the file specified. HRESULT: 0x80070002
   at Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.SafeNativeMethods.ThrowOnErrorCode(Int32 hrError) in c:\Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl\SafeNativeMethods.cs:line 1678
   at Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.SafeNativeMethods.IpcGetTemplateList(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean forceDownload, Boolean suppressUI, Boolean offline, Boolean hasUserConsent, Form parentForm, CultureInfo cultureInfo) in c:\Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl\SafeNativeMethods.cs:line 137
   at IPC.GetTemplates() in c:\IPC.cs

Also, I have set up a post build event to make sure the manifest file gets created every time the code is compiled. The application is a WCF service hosted in a windows service. I have a very simple console app that works.

Any help in resolving this error and any AD RMS examples using managed code would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that may run into this issue I was able to resolve my problem by adding SafeNativeMethods.IpcSetAPIMode(APIMode.Server); to my static constructor like this:

```
static IPC()
    {
        SafeNativeMethods.IpcInitialize();
        SafeNativeMethods.IpcSetAPIMode(APIMode.Server);
    }
```

Comment: How did you get RMS to authenticate the current user though? I keep getting an error saying it can't do so.